# initWithFrame in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

In earlier versions of Xcode, when I create a new subclass of UIView the code below is automatically generated in the implementation file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code...
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm trying to reacquaint myself with it again and now it seems it's not automatically generated anymore. Is there a reason for that? Is this not the proper way of doing it anymore?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add manually so there is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...now it seems it's not automatically generated anymore. Is there a reason for that? Is this not the proper way of doing it anymore?

The "generated" code really just comes from a template file, and all that has happened is that the template file changed at some point. `-initWithFrame:` and `-iniWithCoder:` are still both valid default initializers for `UIView`, and you should override one or both of them in your class if they're needed.

I don't know the actual reason behind the change to the template, but perhaps it was because there's nothing particularly special about the initializer methods compared to the various other methods in UIView that can be overridden. Nearly every UIView subclass needs to override `-drawRect:`, so it makes sense to include that in the template, but that's not true for `-initWithFrame:` or `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: Thank you. I realize some people may find the question mundane but I have always been obsessed with the 'why' sometimes to the point of triviality.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a "hard" reason. Keep in mind that such autogenerated code is for convenience.

However, there might be two reasons:

A. You cannot say whether this is an useful initializer for your view subclass. That's guessing. Typically it is a good idea to give the initializer as much properties as possible.

B. If you have an initializer with more args, this is typically the designated initializer. In such a case the generated code is simply wrong, because `-initWithFrame:` becomes a secondary initializer and has to execute the designated initializer. It is no good idea to generate wrong code.

But this is guessing, too.